# Why does this Scala function compile when the argument does not conform to the type constraint?

Tags: scala, types, typechecking

Let's say I have an empty marker trait named `Marker` and some functions with type parameters bound by `Marker`:

```
trait Marker

object Marker {
  def works[M <: Marker](m:M):M = m
  def doesntWork[M <: Marker](f:M => String):String = "doesn't matter"
}
```

The first function works as I expect.  That is, if you pass a parameter which is not a `Marker`, then the code does not compile:

```
scala> works("a string")
<console>:14: error: inferred type arguments [String] do not conform to method works's type parameter bounds [M <: com.joescii.Marker]
       works("a string")
       ^
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("a string")
 required: M
       works("a string")
             ^
```

However, I am able to pass a parameter to the second function which does not conform to `Marker`.  Specifically, I can pass a function of type `String => String` and the code happily compiles and runs:

```
scala> doesntWork( (str:String) => "a string" )
res1: String = doesn't matter
```

I would expect this call to `doesntWork` to fail to compile.  Can anyone explain to me why it compiles and how I can change the function signature to prevent the types from checking in such cases?

*Full disclosure: the above contrived example is a simplified version of [this outstanding issue for lift-ng](https://github.com/joescii/lift-ng/issues/12).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M => String` is actually a `Function1[M, String]`. If you look at the definition:

```
 trait Function1[-T1, +R]
```

So `M` becomes contravariant, which means that for `M1 >: M2`, `Function1[M1, String] <: Function1[M2, String]`, let's say `M1 = Any` then `Function1[Any, String] <: Function1[Marker, String]`.

And input of `doesntWork` - `f` is also contravariant, which means that you can pass something smaller than `M => String`, and as I've just shown, `Any => String` is smaller than `Marker => String`, so it passess completely fine.

You can also pass `String => String` because of yours `[M <: Marker]`, which finally induces compiler to interpret `M` as `Nothing`, so even `String => String` becomes bigger than `M => String`.

---

To solve your problem, just introduce  wrapper, which will make your type invariant:

```
scala> case class F[M](f: M => String)
defined class F

scala> def doesntWork[M <: Marker](f:F[M]):String = "doesn't matter"
doesntWork: [M <: Marker](f: F[M])String

scala> doesntWork(F((str: String) => "a string"))
<console>:18: error: inferred type arguments [String] do not conform to method doesntWork's type parameter bounds [M <: Marker]
              doesntWork(F((str: String) => "a string"))
              ^
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : F[String]
 required: F[M]
              doesntWork(F((str: String) => "a string"))
                          ^
scala> doesntWork(F((str: Any) => "a string"))
<console>:18: error: inferred type arguments [Any] do not conform to method doesntWork's type parameter bounds [M <: Marker]
              doesntWork(F((str: Any) => "a string"))
              ^
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : F[Any]
 required: F[M]
Note: Any >: M, but class F is invariant in type M.
You may wish to define M as -M instead. (SLS 4.5)
              doesntWork(F((str: Any) => "a string"))

scala> doesntWork(F((str: Marker) => "a string"))
res21: String = doesn't matter

scala> trait Marker2 extends Marker
defined trait Marker2

scala> doesntWork(F((str: Marker) => "a string"))
res22: String = doesn't matter

scala> doesntWork(F((str: Marker2) => "a string"))
res23: String = doesn't matter
```

It's usually bad to recommend such implicit conversions, but seems fine here (if you won't overuse `F`):

```
scala> implicit def wrap[M](f: M => String) = F(f)
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
wrap: [M](f: M => String)F[M]

scala> doesntWork((str: Marker) => "a string")
res27: String = doesn't matter

scala> doesntWork((str: String) => "a string")
<console>:21: error: inferred type arguments [String] do not conform to method doesntWork's type parameter bounds [M <: Marker]
              doesntWork((str: String) => "a string")
              ^
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : F[String]
 required: F[M]
              doesntWork((str: String) => "a string")
                                       ^
```

Comment: But the OP is passing `(str:String) => "a string"` as argument -- this is not of type `Any => String` (nor any subtype of it) ?

Comment: This is still helpful, though.  I was not thinking about the fact that `M => String` is actually `Function1[M, String]` which might have set off my mental flag to consider contravariance.  I'm familiar with the concept, but I certainly still do not _know_ it. :)

Comment: @joescii Yeah, I forgot to mention about final `M <: Marker`, which makes your `M` - `Nothing`, so even `String => String` becomes bigger

Comment: @dk14: Can you help me understand how to accomplish what I have in mind? I want `doesntWork( (str:String) => "a string" )` to fail to compile, but if I declare `case class Container(str:String) extends Marker` then `doesntWork( (obj:Container) => "stuff" )` should compile. I initially thought flipping the type parameter to `[M >: Marker]` would do the trick, but it causes BOTH to fail to compile.

Comment: @joescii How about wrapper `case class F[M](f: M => String)`? It should make type invariant

Comment: @dk14 I would prefer not requiring callers wrap their functions to keep the DSL clean, but maybe that's what has to be done. I naively copy/pasted this case class, reverted the type param to `[M <: Marker]` and it appears to work. Are there other alternatives? Perhaps a macro can read the type and add the F wrap at compile time?

Comment: @joescii I've added implicit as an alternative - see answer's update

Answer (score 6):

The code compiles because of contravariance. You can see that by giving the inferred type parameter explicitly:

```
doesntWork[Nothing]((str: String) => "a string")
```

This is a general problem. There are various techniques to work around that, but they usually boil down to constraining `T` to be an instance of some type class.

Comment: Thanks for answering here and tweeting at me, It seems I simply needed to declare it as `doesntWork[M >: Marker] ...`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Flipping the angle bracket is NOT the magic trick. It causes even valid function to fail.  For instance, if I create `case class Container(str:String) extends Marker` this valid case does not compile: `doesntWork( (obj:Container) => "stuff" )`

Comment: @joescii Advanced usage of generics has caused me nothing but grief in the past, but once you get experienced with it, I can only hope it gets better.